# Python prints messages not sequentially

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, python-3.7, stderr

if I have this code

```
def soft_assert(condition):
    if not condition:
        print('start')
        traceback.print_stack()
        print('finish')

soft_assert(False)
soft_assert(False)
```

the output is different every time I run it:

```
  File "/Users/spleshakov/Documents/api-testing-with-pytest/tenants/test_uc.py", line 38, in <module>
    soft_assert(False, 'message 1')
  File "/Users/spleshakov/Documents/api-testing-with-pytest/tenants/test_uc.py", line 30, in soft_assert
    traceback.print_stack()
  File "/Users/spleshakov/Documents/api-testing-with-pytest/tenants/test_uc.py", line 41, in <module>
    soft_assert(False, 'message 4')
  File "/Users/spleshakov/Documents/api-testing-with-pytest/tenants/test_uc.py", line 30, in soft_assert
    traceback.print_stack()
start
finish
start
finish
```

or

```
start
finish
start
finish
  File "/Users/spleshakov/Documents/api-testing-with-pytest/tenants/test_uc.py", line 38, in <module>
    soft_assert(False)
  File "/Users/spleshakov/Documents/api-testing-with-pytest/tenants/test_uc.py", line 30, in soft_assert
    traceback.print_stack()
  File "/Users/spleshakov/Documents/api-testing-with-pytest/tenants/test_uc.py", line 41, in <module>
    soft_assert(False)
  File "/Users/spleshakov/Documents/api-testing-with-pytest/tenants/test_uc.py", line 30, in soft_assert
    traceback.print_stack()
```

The output can be in any order you can think of

This doesn't make sense to me, I can't find an answer, so I was hoping the community can help me with these questions:

1. Why this is happening?
2. How do I make wait one `print` to finish, before doing another one?

Thanks

Comment: is this some kind of analogue of javascirpt Promise?

Comment: I can't recreate this behaviour on 3.7.6. Works as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is it prints by default to the `stderr`, not the `stdout`:

```
# Used by print_stack
def print_list(extracted_list, file=None):
    if file is None:  # Note here
        file = sys.stderr
    for item in StackSummary.from_list(extracted_list).format():
        print(item, file=file, end="")
```

You're getting out-of-order output because the two streams are being printed to the same console at once.

Specify the `file` argument so it all gets printed to the same stream:

```
from sys import stdout

def soft_assert(condition):
    if not condition:
        print('start')
        traceback.print_stack(file=stdout)  # Print to stdout
        print('finish')
```